# how to Merge the .html file into one Master file with all scope values from releated html files in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

hi all i using angular js i have three html file like.Header,Menu and Footer.html i combined and show ecah html file in each div through id Now the three html file into one html file name is called Master.html

## Code used for link html

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#navbar-container").load("header.html");
        $("#sidebar").load("slidebar.html" );
        $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });

</script>
```

Header.html

i have a one scope variable in header page and it's shows correctly scope variable like say hello world.but when i combined into that means i merge into master page it's not working that scope values are not fetched i don't why anyone help to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Please show how did You initialize the "scope variable" in header? 
I think what You want to use here is the [`ngInclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive which includes additional `html` code into current template.

So You'r example might look like:

```
<div ng-include="header.html"></div>;
....
```

Comment: i header i just show one show variable like{{hello}} from controller that's all